# Java Exceptions in Method Definition

Tags: java, exception

When do I have to write the throwable Exception in the Method Definition?

For example my constructor works with both:

```
public Test(int s, String t) {
  if (s <= 0 || t == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  this.s = s;
  this.t = t;
}
```

or:

```
public Test(int s, String t) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  if (s <= 0 || t == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  this.s = s;
  this.t = t;
}
```

And this method works without it as well:

```
public int mult(int n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  return n * this.s;
}
```

Comment: You can check [the documentation for an exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) to see if it extends `RuntimeException`. If it does, then the compiler doesn't force you to handle or declare it.

Comment: Or you can read up on the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) regarding exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IllegalArgumentException` inherits from `RuntimeException`. `RuntimeException`and all classes that inherit from it are unchecked exceptions and do not have to be declared. See the JavaDoc of `RuntimeException`:

```
/**
 * {@code RuntimeException} and its subclasses are <em>unchecked
 * exceptions</em>.  Unchecked exceptions do <em>not</em> need to be
 * declared in a method or constructor's {@code throws} clause if they
 * can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and
 * propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.
 */
```